# Handling multiple user roles in Ionic 3 apps | Angular apps

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am developing an application which has multiple user roles. Lets say for example, there are 50 user roles ( hypothetically ) and I need to show the content on the app based on these user roles. Now one way to do this is to add a user flag in the JSON returned from the server when the user is logged in if we have two roles such as admin or non admin. e.g.:

```
{'userid':'abc',token:'ggded678932djkhd8hsh',role : '...'}
```

and then have an NgIf In your template :

```
< div class="someclass" *ngIf="currentUser.role==='...'"> Content < /div>
```

But this is not feasible if the number of user roles increase with time. What should be the approach in this scenario?

Comment: Why not loop over the items in your template and use `*ngIf` or `*ngSwitch` may be